# Get RSA custom container key list using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rsa

Is there anyway to get custom key container list that I already made?

Example:
I make Machine key "MyKeys1", "MyKeys2", "MyKeys3" ect. In case I forgot any key that I have made, can I retrieve it using aspnet_regiis?

```
flag
```

I already tried this:

1. `aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp`
2. `aspnet_regiis -pc "MachineKeys2" -exp`

Can I retrieve those key container using aspnet_regiis? because in Crypto/RSA/MachineKeys, the files name just only random number. In case I forgot, what keys that I have ever made. Is it possible to retrieve it using aspnet_regiis?

Comment: Kim, what have you tried?

Comment: I already tried this:
1. aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp
2. aspnet_regiis -pc "MachineKeys2" -exp

can I retrieve those key container using aspnet_regiis? because in Crypto/RSA/MachineKeys, the files name just only random number. In case I forgot, what keys that I have ever made. Is it possible to retrieve it using aspnet_regiis?

Comment: Key container for the machine account usually saved in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA.

Comment: Here is how to do it in powershell, works great! https://security.stackexchange.com/a/146692/43858

Answer (score 5):

Building on ShaneC's mention of Derek W's short c# program, you can save some time by just opening the files within %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys in a text editor. The key container name will be the only readable part.

Comment: I later found that this doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a similar solution, I came across this [blog post recommending KeyPal](https://mysoftwarenotes.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/list-rsa-key-container-names/):

> It’s a simple open source app called KeyPal.  Download it, open up a
> command prompt and run it.  At start up it gives you a list of user
> keys, a list of commands and a blank prompt (with no “>” or anything
> to indicate it’s a prompt).  To list machine level key containers just
> type “LM”, press Enter and there they are!

[Derek W's answer on security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/102923) also recommends KeyPal, his answer includes a short C# program that lists all key container names that currently
exist on the server